# How to increase snackbar height and adjust text size in react native?

Tags: react-native, snackbar

I am using react-native-snackbar in my application i want to show message with snackbar. how to set height and make message text size bigger in snackbar any possible ways to do in react native.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of now

https://github.com/cooperka/react-native-snackbar/issues/122